# Ping not showing date

Tags: linux, shell

I'm saving the ping result to a file, but sometimes the date is not shown. I've tried some pings and found out that the date is not displayed when 0 packets were received but not always. The first ping I'm copying here has 0 received packets and shows the date, last one does not.

```
[jsmith@localhost ~]$ ping 192.168.100.2 -D -c 1 -I eth0
PING 192.168.100.2 (192.168.100.2) from 192.168.100.3 eth0: 56(84) bytes of data.
[1424572632.214329] From 192.168.100.3 icmp_seq=1 Destination Host Unreachable

--- 192.168.100.2 ping statistics ---
1 packets transmitted, 0 received, +1 errors, 100% packet loss, time 0ms

[jsmith@localhost ~]$ ping 192.168.100.2 -D -c 1 -I eth0
PING 192.168.100.2 (192.168.100.2) from 192.168.100.3 eth0: 56(84) bytes of data.
[1424572638.603008] 64 bytes from 192.168.100.2: icmp_seq=1 ttl=64 time=0.374 ms

--- 192.168.100.2 ping statistics ---
1 packets transmitted, 1 received, 0% packet loss, time 0ms
rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 0.374/0.374/0.374/0.000 ms

[jsmith@localhost ~]$ ping 192.168.100.2 -D -c 1 -I eth0
PING 192.168.100.2 (192.168.100.2) from 192.168.100.3 eth0: 56(84) bytes of data.
[1424572645.153724] 64 bytes from 192.168.100.2: icmp_seq=1 ttl=64 time=0.315 ms

--- 192.168.100.2 ping statistics ---
1 packets transmitted, 1 received, 0% packet loss, time 0ms
rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 0.315/0.315/0.315/0.000 ms

[jsmith@localhost ~]$ ping 192.168.100.2 -D -c 1 -I eth0
PING 192.168.100.2 (192.168.100.2) from 192.168.100.3 eth0: 56(84) bytes of data.

--- 192.168.100.2 ping statistics ---
1 packets transmitted, 0 received, 100% packet loss, time 0ms
```

What is wrong?

Comment: Here is a solution for your answer in 


[askububtu](http://askubuntu.com/questions/137233/how-to-command-ping-display-time-and-date-of-ping)

Comment: The first and last execution a re different: in the first case, you actually did receive an icmp packet from 192.168.100.3 telling that 192.168.100.2 is unrecheable; in the latter no packet was received.